# How to call if statements on arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Console {
public static void main(String[] args) {
while (3>2) {
Random rand1 = new Random();
Random rand2 = new Random();
Random rand3 = new Random();
Random rand4 = new Random();
Random rand5 = new Random();
Random rand6 = new Random();
Random rand7 = new Random();
Random rand8 = new Random();
int onenum = rand1.nextInt(2);
int twonum = rand2.nextInt(2);
int threenum = rand3.nextInt(2);
int fournum = rand4.nextInt(2);
int fivenum = rand5.nextInt(2);
int sixnum = rand6.nextInt(2);
int sevennum = rand7.nextInt(2);
int eightnum = rand8.nextInt(2);
int binary[] = {onenum, twonum, threenum, fournum, fivenum, sixnum, sevennum, eightnum};
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(binary));
```

How can I check if, say the first number of the binary array is one?

Currently if I run, i get an output of like {1, 0, 1} ect

Comment: why is there  a condition while 3>2 ,do you want a infinite loop??

Comment: This piece of code looks so cute. Especially the 3>2... :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
if(binary[0] == 1) {
    //do something
}
```

`0` is the first element in array, since the fact of `Arrays` is a `0` based.

**Side note:** You don't have to declare a new object from `Random` to get a number, you can use the same object like:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int onenum = rand.nextInt(2);
int twonum = rand.nextInt(2);
int threenum = rand.nextInt(2);
// and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using an index to access to an element in a specific position of an array:

```
if (someArray[position] == something)
```

In your case, to check the first element, it would be:

```
if (binary[0] == 1)
```

**Note**:

- Indices in most programming languages start with `0` so the first element would be in the index `0` of the array. The second in the index `1`. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Gosh i can reduce your code so much!! Analyse and see that this code does same as yours.

```
while (3>2) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] binary = new int[8];
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        binary[i] = rand.nextInt(2);
    if(binary[0] == 1)
         //if first number is 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this to check if first element equals to 1:

```
if (binary[0] == 1)
{
    //do whatever here..
}
```

**Other issues about your codes**

- I realized you use `while (3>2)`. You can use `while(true)` if you want it to be an infinite loop.
- You only need to create **one** random object to create multiple random numbers. Do it like this..

.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
oneNum = rnd.nextInt(2);
twoNum = rnd.nextInt(2);
threeNum = rnd.nextInt(2);
```

You can even do it this way (using an array to store the random numbers):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] num = new int[8];
for (int x=0; x<num.length; x++)
    num[x] = rnd.nextInt(2);
```